# Sign of second partial derivatives and mixed partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand how to find the signs of pure and mixed partial order derivatives. Here is what I have concluded so far.

If $f(x,y)$ is decreasing along the $\text{x-axis}$ then $f_x(x,y)$ is also decreasing, additionally if $f(x,y)$ is decreasing along the $\text{y-axis}$ then $f_y(x,y)$ is also decreasing.

If $f(x,y)$ is increasing along the $\text{x-axis}$ then $f_x(x,y)$ is also increasing, additionally if $f(x,y)$ is increasing along the $\text{y-axis}$ then $f_y(x,y)$ is also increasing.

One determines if $f(x,y)$ is decreasing or increasing by looking at the values of $f(x,y) = z$ in the positive direction of each axis. The $z$ values are represented in the image below on each level curve. $z$ also represents the height of the 3D surface.

If $f_x(x,y)$ is decreasing then $f_x(x,y)$ is concave down. Therefore, $f_{xx}(x,y) \lt 0$.

If $f_x(x,y)$ is increasing then $f_x(x,y)$ is concave up. Therefore, $f_{xx}(x,y) \gt 0$.

If $f_y(x,y)$ is decreasing then $f_y(x,y)$ is concave down. Therefore, $f_{yy}(x,y) \lt 0$.

If $f_y(x,y)$ is increasing then $f_y(x,y)$ is concave up. Therefore, $f_{yy}(x,y) \gt 0$.

Is what I'm saying above correct, and does this always hold true?

The part that gets me confused is the distance between the level curves. Do level curves that are further apart represent concave up? Level curves that are densely packed represent concave down?

Also, what can I extrapolate from the information above to obtain what the signs of the mixed partial derivative are? $f_{xy}(x,y)$ and $f_{yx}(x,y)$.

Thank you!

[image: Shows level curves]

Comment: If the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is decreasing then all you know is that $f_x(x,y) \le 0$.

Comment: how do i find out about $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$?